# What is the use of forward index in search, as we use inverted index in elastic search and get all the documents containing a particular word/words?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, inverted-index, forward-indexing

Elastic search use inverted index which is totally understandable because it returns all the documents containing the word we searched for.
But I do not understand where do we use forward index? Like, we don't search for document and expect words containing in that particular document.
Is there any practical use case for forward index? Any company using it for its product?

Comment: did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31761889/10348758), there is no technical difference between the forward index and the inverted index. Forward index is a list of terms contained within a particular document. The inverted index would be a list of documents containing a given term.

Please go through this [blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-indexing-for-beginners-part3), where it is clearly mentioned that the forward index is pretty fast when indexing and have less efficient queries.

Whereas inverted indexing have slower indexing, but fast query. To get a detailed explanation of the inverted index, you can refer to this [article](https://www.devinline.com/2018/09/elasticsearch-inverted-index-and-its-storage.html#:%7E:text=Elasticsearch%20uses%20a%20special%20data,documents%20in%20which%20it%20appears.) and this [blog.](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-from-the-bottom-up)

Answer (score 0):

forward index are index based on sorting or items in such a way that they are retrievable and easily located. So forward index are perfect for scenarios where by providing a word or a search key, a database can easily identify the positions of the record quickly based on the sorting technique of the index.

But inverted index aren’t based on this, inverted index words based on ranking of a word on where they appear in a document and how relevant they are.

So a classical example is you entered a shop and told a seller to give you a book called “Zilla my country”. He or she could check his record and know what part of the store zilla would be located. This is for example simply based off on alphabetical order

But the above would fail if the title does match exact. For example “my country zilla”, this would point to the wrong place to search for.

The perfect use case of inverted index is when the words are searched against and every book title that match against such word is ranked accordingly.

This way you only need to remember some phrase of the title to find the document. So inverted index isn’t for retrieval purpose. As it clearly didn’t have to point to where you would find the book in the store. Rather it was used to find the book you were looking for. While forward index would help you to find the location of the book in same store